# 3 screens on W500 + ATI V5700 + docking station

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display, lenovo-laptop, docking-station

I've got Lenovo W500 with D-SUB and DVI ports. Most of the time I work with a docking station which has D-SUB and DVI ports, as well. I used to have laptop + 22" monitor (DVI) configuration.

Now I've got laptop + 22" (DVI) + 19" (D-SUB). I was trying to configure everythin but with no success.

I've got ATI V5700 in my laptop. And my ATI CCC allows me to only have one external monitor attached at the time. :(

Is there any workaround to this situation? I'd like to have the configuration I've just descripted: laptop + 22" (DVI) + 19" (D-SUB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ATI V5700 in your Thinkpad W500 only support two simultaneous displays.  For a triple monitor setup you'll need to pick up a USB video device.  I'd stay away from the 'Lenovo USB Port Replicator with Digital Video' it's a first gen product that has power save/rotation issues, but a newer DisplayLink (e.g. this [$69 DL-195 based product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0038P1TP4)) supports 1920x1200 and even comes with the necessary adapters so you can use this with a vga, dvi or hdmi monitor. Windows/Linux/OSX all supported.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, only the newest ATI cards series 59xx allow more that 3 monitors to be connected at the same time.